# PyAudio compilation on Raspbian

Tags: python, raspbian, pyaudio

When trying to install `pyaudio` with `pip install pyaudio` on Raspbian, I get:

```
Collecting pyaudio
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pyaudio
Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external pyaudio to allow).
No distributions at all found for pyaudio
```

**How to build `pyaudio` with Raspbian?**
Does it need a specific tool?

Comment: Did you ever try "pip install pyaudio --allow-external pyaudio --allow-unverified pyaudio"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
apt-get install jackd2 libjack-jackd2-0 qjackctl sonic-pi supercollider supercollider-server

git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git
cd pyaudio
python setup.py install
```

*Remark:* this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

would install pyaudio version 0.2.4, which doesn't support working with stream `callback`.

Answer (score 1):

Try install with the package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

Comment: Thanks @MalikBrahimi! Would you perhaps have an idea for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865331/list-devices-with-pyaudio-on-raspberry-pi ? :)

Comment: No, I had no idea PyAudio could even list devices. Do you have appropriate drivers installed? Have you tried running now that PyAudio is properly installed?

Comment: yes I tried with PyAudio installed, but I get these errors

Comment: That version from `apt-get` is obsolete. I really need to be able to compile it on my Raspberry Pi.